# add suggestions to Minecraft give command with PaperMC

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I am trying to add suggestions (more options in tab complete) to the items part of the Minecraft give command with brigadier from PaperMC. Their is almost no doc for this and I can't figure it out.

I want to add custom items to the tab complete list of the give command.

I tried manually looking into the command tree you get from the AsyncPlayerSendCommandsEvent event. I found a CommandNode with the name items in the give command, but I couldn't find where to add arguments.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. You're talking about the tab completion?

Comment: Yes, but I asked in the PaperMC discord and the TabCompleteEvent doesn't work on vanilla commands

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.